# How to add a different image in every different flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a noob in coding. Actually, I just started less than 5 days ago. I am looking at a tutorial from a developer in youtube which is doing really well. So I was just going along with the tutorial. I was trying to make my work a little bit different from his. But, I am now stuck at this dilemma.

I wanted to have different background image in every flex box in the "Services" section. But for some reason when I try to create a separate div for the image (just like the `.icon` and the `<p>`) it doesn't seem to work well, or the image does not sit well in the entire box.

When you look at the code as it is, all of them have the same background image mainly because the main container holds the background image.

I just can't seem to find a way how to get each box with a different background image.

Please help!

```css
/* Services Section */

#Services {
  background-color: #f4f6ff;
}

#Services .services {
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #f4f6ff;
}

.header-title {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#Services .section-header p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#Services .services-cards {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#Services .services-content {
  flex-basis: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: url(./img/customer-support.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 10px 5%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Services .services-content::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #0a2647 0%, #584a2a 100%);
  opacity: 80%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#Services .services-cards .icon {
  height: 90px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

`enter code here` #Services .services-content h2 {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: gold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<! -- Services Section -->
<section id="Services">
  <div class="services container">
    <div class="section-header">
      <h1 class="header-title">Services</h1>
      <p>I have worked with successful businesses over the years, I have helped companies activate their audience through social media marketing, facilitated the on-boarding process for their new customers.<br><br>I also managed projects for 20 plus brand
        ambassadors and led company team members so they can produce quality and engaging content delivered to our social media channels efficiently.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services-cards">
      <div class="services-content">
        <div class="icon"><img src="" /></div>
        <h2>Customer Support</h2>
        <p>I have worked as a BPO Rep for 3 years. I have the fundamental knowledge in handling customer calls, emails and provide the adequate support, so that you can focus on the important aspect of your business.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-cards">
      <div class="services-content">
        <div class="icon"><img src="" /></div>
        <h2>Administrative Assistant</h2>
        <p>Data entry, Research, Invoicing, Calendar Management, CRM maintenance, Appointment Setting, Recruitment, and more. I will take charge of the routine back-office tasks and you can keep focus on what matters for your brand.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-cards">
      <div class="services-content">
        <div class="icon"><img src="" /></div>
        <h2>Porject Management</h2>
        <p>Launching a new product? Do you need help in Content creation and Scheduling? Or are you looking for a point-person to lead your marketing team and start pulling-in audience for your brand? I have 5 years of Social Media management experience,
          supported brands with different products catering to different demographics. I can develop a distinct strategy that will work for you. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="services-cards">
      <div class="services-content">
        <div class="icon"><img src="" /></div>
        <h2>Front-End Web Development</h2>
        <p>I can hand-code HTML, CSS with some knowledge in CSS Flexbox, Bootstrap, and Javascript.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you speak about

css

```
#Services .services-content {
...
background-image: url(./img/customer-support.jpg); 
...
}
#Services .services-content::after {
...
background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #0a2647 0%, #584a2a 100%);
...
}
```

and this html

```
<div class="services-content">
...
</div>
```

you just need to add another class that will override this property `background-image` for `.services-content` for each background so

css

```
#Services .first-content {
...
background-image: url(diffrent); 
...
}
#Services .first-content::after {
...
background-image: linear-gradient(diffrent);
...
}
#Services .second-content {
...
background-image: url(diffrent); 
...
}
#Services .second-content::after {
...
background-image: linear-gradient(diffrent);
...
}
```

and then for each html

```
<div class="services-content first-content">
...
</div>
<div class="services-content second-content">
...
</div>
```

That way you will override your `background-image` only and rest of `css` will stay the same

Answer (score 0):

If you mean  a different gradient for each  div.services-content you could try add these selectors in your css:

```html
<style>

        #Services {
        background-color: #f4f6ff;
    }
    #Services .services {
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 1500px;
        margin: 0 auto;


        padding: 50px 0;
        background-color: #f4f6ff;
    }

.header-title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

#Services .section-header p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#Services .services-cards {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#Services .services-content {
    flex-basis: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url(./img/customer-support.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 10px 5%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#Services .services-content::after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #0a2647 0%, #584a2a 100%); */
    opacity: 80%;
    z-index: -1;
}


#Services > div > div:nth-child(2) > div{
background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #0a2647 0%, #584a2a 100%);
}
#Services > div > div:nth-child(3) > div{
background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #0a2647 0%, red 100%);
}
#Services > div > div:nth-child(4) > div{
background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #0a2647 0%, yellow 100%);
}
#Services > div > div:nth-child(5) > div{
background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #0a2647 0%, blue 100%);
}


#Services .services-cards .icon {
    height: 90px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#Services .services-content h2 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: gold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>

<section id="Services">
    <div class="services container">

        <div class="section-header">
            <h1 class="header-title">Services</h1>
            <p>I have worked with successful businesses over the years, I have helped companies activate their audience through social media marketing, facilitated the on-boarding process for their new customers.<br><br>I also managed projects for 20 plus brand ambassadors and led company team members so they can produce quality and engaging content delivered to our social media channels efficiently.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services-cards">
            <div class="services-content">
                <div class="icon"><img src=""/></div>
                <h2>Customer Support</h2>
                <p>I have worked as a BPO Rep for 3 years. I have the fundamental knowledge in handling customer calls, emails and provide the adequate support, so that you can focus on the important aspect of your business.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="services-cards">
            <div class="services-content">
                <div class="icon"><img src=""/></div>
                <h2>Administrative Assistant</h2>
                <p>Data entry, Research, Invoicing, Calendar Management, CRM maintenance, Appointment Setting, Recruitment, and more. I will take charge of the routine back-office tasks and you can keep focus on what matters for your brand.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="services-cards">
            <div class="services-content">
                <div class="icon"><img src=""/></div>
                <h2>Porject Management</h2>
                <p>Launching a new product? Do you need help in Content creation and Scheduling? Or are you looking for a point-person to lead your marketing team and start pulling-in audience for your brand? I have 5 years of Social Media management experience, supported brands with different products catering to different demographics. I can develop a distinct strategy that will work for you. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="services-cards">
            <div class="services-content">
                <div class="icon"><img src=""/></div>
                <h2>Front-End Web Development</h2>
                <p>I can hand-code HTML, CSS with some knowledge in CSS Flexbox, Bootstrap, and Javascript.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```